# Array and object filter javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have following array

```
permissionList: [
        {
            name: "Database",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Database/View",
                    name: "View Database",
                    description: "permission for view database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Database/Add",
                    name: "Add Database",
                    description: "permission for Add database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: "Project",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Project/View",
                    name: "View Project",
                    description: "permission for view Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Project/Add",
                    name: "Add Project",
                    description: "permission for Add Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
```

When someone enters Database/View, It should be filtered as follow.

```
permissionList: [
        {
            name: "Database",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Database/View",
                    name: "View Database",
                    description: "permission for view database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                }
            ],
        },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with two simple functions, one to filter the list of inner permissions, the second to list the list of external permissions if the inner list is not empty.

```
// Function to filter inner permissions if their key is equals to the requested key
function innerFilter(permissions, key) {
   return permissions.filter(permission => permission.key == key);
}


// Function to be called with the permission list. It filter inner
// permissions, than it consider only not empty inner permissions
function outerFilter(list, key) {
    return list
      // make a copy of original items with a list of permissions
      // satisfying the requested key
      .map(item => { 
         return {  
            ...item, 
            permissions: innerFilter(item.permissions, key) 
         } 
      })
      // filter the items having at least 1 inner permission
      // satisfying the requested key
      .filter(item => item.permissions.length > 0)
}
```

and calling it using the outerFilter function

```
var searchedList = outerFilter(permissions, "Database/View");
```

Please consider that this code has not been tested, so typos are possible, take it as an idea. Add if necessary the test for null or undefined values.

Eventually you can combine the two functions in a single function as follow:

```
// Function to be called with the permission list. It filter inner
// permissions, than it consider only not empty inner permissions
function filterByPermissionKey(list, key) {
    return list
      // make a copy of original items with a list of permissions
      // satisfying the requested key
      .map(item => { 
         return {  
            ...item, 
            // Extract the sublist of permissions having the requested key
            permissions: item.permissions.filter(permission => permission.key == key)
         } 
      })
      // filter the items having at least 1 inner permission
      // satisfying the requested key
      .filter(item => item.permissions.length > 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const permissionList = [
        {
            name: "Database",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Database/View",
                    name: "View Database",
                    description: "permission for view database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Database/Add",
                    name: "Add Database",
                    description: "permission for Add database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: "Project",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Project/View",
                    name: "View Project",
                    description: "permission for view Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Project/Add",
                    name: "Add Project",
                    description: "permission for Add Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
    ];
    
    console.log('Permission List Before ==>', permissionList);
    
    const newList = permissionList.filter(eachObj => eachObj.name === "Database");
    console.log('New List ==>', newList);
```

You can do the above .filter() option available to arrays in Javascript

Comment: I want to filter out array in side in object not the you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const permissionList = [{
    name: "Database",
    permissions: [{
        id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
        key: "Database/View",
        name: "View Database",
        description: "permission for view database module",
        createdAt: "",
        updatedAt: "",
      },
      {
        id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
        key: "Database/Add",
        name: "Add Database",
        description: "permission for Add database module",
        createdAt: "",
        updatedAt: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Project",
    permissions: [{
        id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
        key: "Project/View",
        name: "View Project",
        description: "permission for view Project module",
        createdAt: "",
        updatedAt: "",
      },
      {
        id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
        key: "Project/Add",
        name: "Add Project",
        description: "permission for Add Project module",
        createdAt: "",
        updatedAt: "",
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log('Permission List Before ==>', permissionList);

let permissionsOfEachObj = [];

let keys = [];

permissionList.forEach(obj => {
  keys = Object.keys(obj);
});

console.log('Keys ==>', keys);

keys.forEach((key) => {
  if(key === 'permissions') {
    permissionList.forEach(obj => {
      permissionsOfEachObj.push(obj[key]);
    })
  }
});

console.log('Permissions Of Each Object ==>', permissionsOfEachObj);

permissionsOfEachObj = permissionsOfEachObj.flat();
console.log('Permissions Of Each Object after Flatting ==>', permissionsOfEachObj);

const databaseOrView = permissionsOfEachObj.filter(eachObj => eachObj.key === "Database/View");
console.log('Final Output ==>', databaseOrView);
```

Ok. I understood the question now. Please check the required output here now. You have the required console logs to check the answer.

Comment: @GihanPrimesha please approve the answer if you feel it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just one solution refusing to yield to this new pseudo-functional programming religion.
There is nothing generic or reusable in this kind of function, so there is no benefit in immutability and whatnot. Nobody else will ever use it, so either it works here and now or it doesn't.

As always, using plain JavaScript allows you to write faster and safer code by adding trivial, natural optimizations and safety checks, for instance :

- avoiding a truckload of useless shallow copies
- cutting the loop short once you get your result
- forbidding to get more than one result (a key is supposed to be unique)
- forbidding to query a non-existent key

By the way, surely you have your reasons, but once you get one permission, the outer layer of data is just excess luggage.
You could just as well return the actual permission record instead, with or without (shallow) copy, depending on whether you intend to mutate your result or not.
In this particular case, you seem to want to replace the initial list with the result of your filter, so creating an intermediate immutable object is pointless.

```
function GetPermissionByKey (list, key)
{
    // if you want to check for unicity of key
    // let result = undefined;
    for (item of list) {                                     // browse all items
        for (permission of item.permissions) {               // browse all keys of each item
            if (permission.key == key) {                     // found the key
                // ...variant to enforce key uniqueness:
                // if (result !== undefined) throw 'duplicate key ' + key;
                // result = [{...item, permissions: [{...permission}]}];
                return [{...item, permissions: [{...permission}]}]; // full deep copy
                // ...or a shallow copy
                // return [{...item, permissions: [permission]}];
                // ...or you might just drop the excess luggage:
                // return permission;
                // ...or return a shallow copy if you really want one:
                // return {...permission};
            }
        }
    }
    // ...if you checked for unicity of keys
    // return result ?? []; // return an empty array if key was not found
    // ...or without unicity check
    return [];
    // ...or consider using a wrong key a program error
    // throw 'key not found ' + key;
}
```

Sample output using your example input:

```
var res = GetPermissionByKey(permissionList,"Database/View");
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(res,undefined,2)}`)

[
  {
    "name": "Database",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "id": "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
        "key": "Database/View",
        "name": "View Database",
        "description": "permission for view database module",
        "createdAt": "",
        "updatedAt": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const permissionList = [
        {
            name: "Database",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Database/View",
                    name: "View Database",
                    description: "permission for view database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Database/Add",
                    name: "Add Database",
                    description: "permission for Add database module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: "Project",
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2dc586c6bfbbd",
                    key: "Project/View",
                    name: "View Project",
                    description: "permission for view Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
                {
                    id: "610c3b02e5e2d3w586c6bfbfs",
                    key: "Project/Add",
                    name: "Add Project",
                    description: "permission for Add Project module",
                    createdAt: "",
                    updatedAt: "",
                },
            ],
        },
    ]

console.log({name: permissionList[0].name, permissions: [permissionList[0].permissions[0]]})
```